# MongoDB find document with known hash of field

Tags: mongodb, hash

I have a collection of documents like `{ name : 'john', password : 'secret' }` in my MongoDB. Now I want to make an authentication process in my application using this database. For the purposes of security the application itself doesn't know the password, instead it knows only its md5-checksum `5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69`.

Is it possible for me to use `findOne` request in order to check user credentials?

Of course I can just do `x = db.users.findOne({name: 'john'})`, then apply md5 to `x.password` and compare it with known checksum, but this is rather bad approach since the application would know the real password.

I'm looking for some command like

> db.users.findOne({name: 'john', password : {$md5 : '5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69'} } )

Any chance such expression exists?

Comment: Storing raw passwords in your database is actually much, much worse than for your application to know user's passwords during the login phase. If someone steals the database, they will have direct access to all passwords, which is a disaster.

Comment: What you should do instead is store MD5 hashes (salted) in MongoDB. Then your queries will become very straightforward, too.